# Simply adding/removing/sorting data

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple data handler class.

I would like to know if I can make my class more simple and efficient for doing the identical feature.

**My Code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MyData
{
public:
    void add(const pair<string *, int> &elem)
    {
        size_t index = findIndex(elem.first);
        if (index != -1) //if key exists, update the value
        {
            myVec[index].second = elem.second;
            return;
        }
        myVec.push_back(elem);
    }
    void remove(string *strPtr)
    {
        size_t index = findIndex(strPtr);
        if (index != -1)
            myVec.erase(myVec.begin() + index);
    }
    void sort()
    {
        std::sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), comp);
    }
    void print()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << *myVec[i].first << " : " << myVec[i].second << '\n';
        }
    }
private:
    size_t findIndex(string *strPtr)
    {
        auto it = find_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), [&](pair<string *, int> const & ref)
                          {
                              return ref.first == strPtr;
                          });
        if (it != myVec.end())
            return std::distance(myVec.begin(), it);
        return -1;
    }
    static bool comp(const pair<string *, int> &a, const pair<string *, int> &b)
    {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
    vector<pair<string *, int>> myVec;
};

int main()
{
    string fruits[] = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Grapes", "Lemon"};
    MyData data;
    data.add(make_pair(&fruits[0], 13));
    data.add(make_pair(&fruits[1], 52));
    data.add(make_pair(&fruits[2], 33));
    data.add(make_pair(&fruits[3], 8));
    data.add(make_pair(&fruits[4], 22));
    data.add(make_pair(&fruits[1], 17));
    data.sort();
    data.remove(&fruits[4]);
    data.print();
}
```

**The Result :**

```
Grapes : 8
Apple : 13
Banana : 17
Orange : 33
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: is there any reason to not use a standard container like `std::map` for the task?

Comment: @Sandro4912 I couldn't sort values easily&efficiently using `std::map` so I decided to go with `std::vector`. Please see my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52055430/how-to-sort-a-stdmap-by-ascending-order-of-value

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `using namespace std`. Its considered bad practice.

See [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice&ved=2ahUKEwji0KCo1JDdAhXMKewKHZX-AxQQFjAFegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3k3HuVD-pzfPiMJTh1OKtq)

Why pass std::string by pointer?
In C++ we have references &. They safe you the burden of dereference the pointers.

Dont use c-style arrays like

```
string fruits[] = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Grapes", "Lemon"};
```

In c++ you can use std::vector or std::array(if the size is fixed) for the task:

```
std::vector<std::string> fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Grapes", "Lemon"};
```

Whats the whole purpose of the structure? You could just use a std::vector> and use  std::find and std::sort to accomplish what you want to archieve with youre data structure.